# get zend form fileupload values to another input field

Tags: zend-framework2

```
<?php echo $this->form->getElement("logo");  ?>
<div id="BrowserVisible">
<input type="text" id="halal" />
<input type="button" value="Upload" id="button" />
</div>
```

(form->getElement("logo");  ?>)field is genrated by zend form, when i select the image file from PC, the upload file path or file name is show in input field, that also copy in (`<input type="text" id="halal" />`), how can i do that.

Tahnks in advanced

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Now it's not clear what you have, what you want to achieve and what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code with this :

```
<?php echo $this->form->get("logo");  ?>
```